# Calling JavaScript from within PHP logic error

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, logic

I am printing out a number of rows from my database. Each row contains one td which contains which id is the respective row number(row numbers start at 1).

As each row is echoed, I update the rows with addresses using javascript .appendChild(), addresses whose co-ordinates have been called from the db.

The first 5 rows co-ordinates have been correctly converted into addresses, and the remaining rows have the correct co-ordinates called from the db(I know because I checked the source) however the address being entered in the row is always the value of the last row on the db.

Please note that the co-ordinates are being converted to addresses using google maps api.

```
if ( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ){ 

  $i = 1;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    ?>

    <script>
      initialize();
      var counter = 1;

      function initialize() {
        var geocoder;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['latitude'] ?>,<?php echo $row['longitude'] ?>);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
              var txt = results[0].formatted_address;
              var newtext = document.createTextNode(txt);
              document.getElementById("address" + counter).appendChild(newtext);
              counter++;
            } else {
              alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            //alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

      setInterval(convert, 2);

      function convert() {
        initialize();
      }
    </script>

    <?php
    echo "<td id='address" . $i . "'></td>";
    $i++;
  }
```

**Solution**

After a bit of thinking, and a lot of googling, I solved it! Entire code below for anyone else that might stumble on this!

```
<?php
    // security check
    $account_type = $_COOKIE["account_type"];
    if($account_type != "canvass_leader" && $account_type != "leader" && $account_type != "canvasser"){
        header("location:login.php");
    }
    $username_cookie2 = $_COOKIE["username_cookie"];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"/> 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <title>Canvassing Data</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #header #welcome #para{
            margin-top: -84px;
        }
    </style>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function setUp() {
            window.counter = 1;

            setInterval(initialize, 700);
        }


        function initialize() {
            var geocoder;
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            var lat = document.getElementById("lat" + counter);
            var lng = document.getElementById("lng" + counter);
            //alert(lat.innerHTML);
            //alert(lng.innerHTML);

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat.innerHTML,lng.innerHTML);

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    if (results[1]) {
                        var txt = results[0].formatted_address;
                        var addressValue = document.createTextNode(txt);

                        $('#lat' + counter).remove();
                        $('#lng' + counter).remove();

                        var element = "#address" + counter;
                        $(element).append(addressValue)
                        counter++;

                    } else {
                        alert('No results found');
                    }
                } else {
                    //alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="setUp()" >

    <div id="wrapper">

        <?php 
            include('header.php'); 

            // connect to server and select databse.
            mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            // get party cookie
            $party = $_COOKIE["party"];

            // set table name
            $tbl_name = "checklist_" . $party;
        ?>


        <div id='info_bubble'>From this page you can view, search and export all collected canvassing data.</div>

        <?php if($account_type == "canvass_leader") { ?>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <form id="" method="post" action="" style="margin: 20px 0 30px 0;">
                    <h3>Search Canvassing Data</h3>
                    <fieldset id="inputs" >
                        <input style="width: 270px;" name="search_name" type="text" placeholder="Search by canvasser name.." >
                        <input style="width: 270px;" name="search_reception" type="text" placeholder="Search by reception at door.." >
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="actions" class="button button-blue">
                        <span><input type="submit" id="submit" name="search" value="Search Data"></span>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
                $search_name = $_POST['search_name']; 
                $search_reception = $_POST['search_reception']; 

                if(strlen($search_name)) {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE canvasser = '$search_name'";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                }
                if(strlen($search_reception)) {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE reception_at_door = '$search_reception'";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                }
            }
            else{
                if($account_type == "canvass_leader") {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE creator = '$username_cookie2'";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                }
                else { // account_type = Leader
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                }
            }



            // display table data           
            echo "<div id='content'>
                    <table class='bordered' border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>House Number</th>
                    <th>Registered to Vote</th>
                    <th>Visited by Candidate</th>
                    <th>Leafleted</th>
                    <th>Canvassed</th>
                    <th>Reception at Door</th>
                    <th>Canvasser</th>
                    </tr>";


            if ( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ){ 

                //$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                //echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

                $i = 1;

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    ?>






                    <?php
                    //echo "<td id='address" . $i . "'></td>";
                    //echo "<td id='address" . $i . "'>" . $row['latitude'] . " ## " . $row['longitude'] . "</td>";
                    //echo "<td id='address" . $i . "'>" . $row['latitude'] . " ## " . $row['longitude'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td id='address" . $i . "'><p id='lat" . $i . "'>" . $row['latitude'] . "</p><p id='lng" . $i . "'>" . $row['longitude'] . "</p></td>";
                    // only set co-ordiantes first, then convert them to address by getElementById and appendChild when dom is ready in js in head of page

                    echo "<td>" . $row['house_number'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['registered_to_vote'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['visited_by_candidate'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['leafleted'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['canvassed'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['reception_at_door'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['canvasser'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                    $i++;


                }
            }

            echo "</table>";    


            if( $account_type == "canvass_leader" || $account_type == "leader"){    
                echo '<form style="margin-top: 10px;" action="dash_data_canvassing_export.php">';
                echo '<fieldset id="actions" class="button button-blue"><span><input type="submit" value="Export Data" id="submit" name="submit"></span></fieldset>';
                echo '</form></div>';
            }

            include('footer.php'); 
        ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Being earnest, this approach is the worst you can have in web development: I strongly advise you to learn separating concerns, i.e. keeping data [mysql], logic [php], presentation [html], client interaction [js] as separate as possible. If you need to retrieve data from your server, either pass it as JSON, or inject it into the DOM with `data-*` attributes [for smaller purposes only].

Comment: How would I use the json together with the php and javascript?

Comment: I suggest you take a step backwards and learn a bit more php, html and javascript. Separate your javascript from your HTML, learn what a domRedy event is and use it. There is unfortunately so much that is wrong in your question so you will not be able to get help unless someone rewrites your code from scratch. Tip: inspect your code in chrome developer tools or firebug that will teach you a lot.